# UIAutomation script not running on device

Tags: ios, ui-automation

For some reason, UIAutomation doesn't want to run on my physical device. I've gotten to run once, but otherwise when I kick it off, it simply sits there reporting "Script has stopped".

I've checked the following:

- Using a developer profile to code sign
- Several different cables, including a first party Apple one
- Restarting my Mac and the iPad
- Cleaning and rebuilding

Other instruments work just fine, I can run allocations and leaks without any issue, automation just refuses to run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and then (eventually) figured it out.

Turns out the build has to be a DEBUG build so that instruments can attach to it.  I edited the scheme build settings for "build for profiling" so that it would build a DEBUG build rather than a RELEASE build and things started working.